# PHP File Uploading system

Tags: php, file-upload

Hey i have a system were in uploading a file. I have a **[script](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/file_upload.php)** I've found online and it seems to work well.

Here is the PHP code:

```
 if((!empty($_FILES["uploaded_file"])) && ($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0)) 
{
    //Check if the file is JPEG image and it's size is less than 350Kb
    $filename = basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);
    if (($ext == "jpg") && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"] < 350000)) 
    {
        //Determine the path to which we want to save this file
            $newname = dirname(__FILE__).'upload/'.$filename;
            //Check if the file with the same name is already exists on the server
        if (!file_exists($newname)) 
        {
            //Attempt to move the uploaded file to it's new place
            if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],$newname))) 
            {
                echo "It's done! The file has been saved as: ".$newname;
            } 
            else 
            {
                echo "Error: A problem occurred during file upload!";
            }
            }
        else
        {
            echo "Error: File ".$_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]." already exists";
            }
    } 
    else 
    {
         echo "Error: Only .jpg images under 350Kb are accepted for upload";
    }
} 
else 
{
     echo "Error: No file uploaded";
}
```

No this works fine if i want to upload a jpg file. But i want to be able to put the file into another directory. because at the moment the upload page is for admin users, they are on a subdomain called admin.mysite.com but the location i want the file to go to is in the members section which is mysite.com/members/video/

Now there are a few bits of code that im not 100% with like "dirname(**FILE**)" what does this do? I guessed it would get the current locations, but i've changed the whole line where so it looks like this:

```
$newname = '../mysite.com/members/video/'.$filename;
```

and

```
$newname = 'http://www.mysite.com/members/video/'.$filename;
```

But nothing. Anyone know how i can change this code so i can copy the file to a new directory?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: http://php.net/dirname... and you won't be able to move a file to a URL like your second attempt.

Comment: This script isn't very secure. Nothing is stopping me from uploading a steal_cookie.js file and change the extension to steal_cookie.jpg. When the file is viewed in the browser, I steal all your cookies.

Comment: There is, its all password protected for just admins accounts to us.

Answer (score 0):

Change $newname to whatever location you want!

```
//Determine the path to which we want to save this file
$newname = dirname(__FILE__).'upload/'.$filename;
```

Comment: I've tried that and it doesn't seem to work. I also changed the permission of the directory i want to send it to to write.

Answer (score 0):

dirname(_ *FILE* _) returns the current directory of the file, in this case, file_upload.php

So, in this script, the $newname will save the uploaded file to /upload/name_of_new_file_uploaded.ext.

You should try to use realpath() instead dirname. Like this:

```
$newname = realpath("../../members/video/") . $filename;
```

depending on you file structure, add/remove the dots.

PS: Remember to change folder permissions, so the php can write on a folder.

Comment: I've just tried that, and changed the permission but i'm getting a permission error :S

Answer (score -1):

For security, you should

1. Put the file in a location that is not accessible by the general web.  /home/uploadedfiles/
2. Change the name of the file.  Store the name of that file in a database and don't let the end users see that actual name.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but its not answering my question.

Comment: That's because the rest of these folks already gave you the right answer.  I'll remember to keep my mouth shut next time.